# SwiftUI Context Menu

Tags: swiftui

My project was using a `List` but I needed a ScrollView wrapped view so I changed the `List` to just a `ForEach` loop with a view and `Divider` in between. I noticed my `Context Menu` doesn't look the same as when it was in the `List` as in the screenshot below.

I'd like the item selected with context menu to look like the `List` item selected since I can no longer use `List` in the code, it doesn't look as pretty. Also I have to press on the image and or text to open the `Context Menu` unlike in a `List` you can select the row. The end result would be to mimic the style of the selected `List` item.

[image]

```swift
/// Context Menu looks terrible
VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 0){
    ForEach(self.welcome.views.dropLast(), id: \.id) { view in
        ForEach(view.views ?? [], id: \.id) { purple in
            ForEach(purple.views, id: \.id) { fluffy in
                VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 0){
                    if viewClass == "FeaturedHeaderView" {
                        Text(title)
                            .font(.title3)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                    } else {
                        HStack (spacing: 15){
                            RequestImage(Url(image), animation: nil)
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                                .clipped()
                                .cornerRadius(13.5)
                            VStack (alignment: .leading){
                                Text(name)
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                Text(author)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
                                    .font(.footnote)
                                Text(repo)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
                                    .font(.caption)
                            }
                        }
                        .contextMenu(ContextMenu(menuItems: {
                            HStack {
                                Button(action: {
                                    openURL(URL(string: "URL")!)
                                }) {
                                    Label("Open in Safari", systemImage: "safari.fill")
                                }
                            }
                        }))
                    }
                }
                Divider()
            }
        }
    }
    .padding(.all, 5)
    .padding(.leading, 5)
}
```

```swift
/// List Context Menu looks great but can't use List in ScrollView
List {
    ForEach(self.welcome.views.dropLast(), id: \.id) { view in
        ForEach(view.views ?? [], id: \.id) { purple in
            ForEach(purple.views.dropLast(), id: \.id) { fluffy in
                VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 0){
                    if viewClass == "FeaturedHeaderView" {
                        Text(title)
                            .font(.title3)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                    } else {
                        HStack (spacing: 15){
                            RequestImage(Url(image), animation: nil)
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                                .clipped()
                                .cornerRadius(13.5)
                            VStack (alignment: .leading){
                                Text(name)
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                Text(author)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
                                    .font(.footnote)
                                Text(repo)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
                                    .font(.caption)
                            }
                        }
                        .contextMenu(ContextMenu(menuItems: {
                            HStack {
                                Button(action: {
                                    openURL(URL(string: "URL")!)
                                }) {
                                    Label("Open in Safari", systemImage: "safari.fill")
                                }
                            }
                        }))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .padding(.all, 10)
    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible solution is to add `background` modifier above `contextMenu`, like

```
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)           // << to make it screen-wide
.background(
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)  // << tune as needed
       .fill(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))  // << fill with system color
)
.contextMenu(ContextMenu(menuItems: {
```

Demo with some replication (used Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4)

[image: demo]